# google-cloud-billing tag abandon / cleanup request

Tags: support, tags, retag-request

I stumbled upon this tag: [google-cloud-billing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-cloud-billing) and found out that it is used mainly for non-programming questions.

Here are the last 5 questions tagged with it:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66897685/any-way-to-know-my-gcp-account-is-paid-account-or-not
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66870313/unable-to-create-an-google-cloud-billing-account
- [Google SQL Instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66797592/google-sql-instance)
- [Can I upgrade committed use discount from 1 year to 3 year?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66792781/can-i-upgrade-committed-use-discount-from-1-year-to-3-year)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66729307/how-do-i-fix-google-cloud-trial-billing-error

The 100 questions in this tag should probably be reviewed / closed / deleted accordingly.

In my opinion, they are all off-topic.

Cloud billing now has [various APIs](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/apis?hl=en) available. I therefore would suggest to **rename** the tag from [google-cloud-billing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-cloud-billing) to *google-cloud-billing-api* and to write an appropriate tag wiki.